# Janela modal "uma vez por sessão"

Tags: jquery

Bom pessoal, pode parecer simples e fácil de se resolver. Mas para quem não saca nada da linguagem, acaba virando um tormento. Vamos lá:

Criei uma janela modal contendo uma imagem de aviso. E inclui as div's com os id's respectivos no html:

```
<div id="fundo">
<div class="janelamodal">
    <img src="aviso.png" title="Aviso Vapores e Sabores" alt="Vapores e Sabores" />
        <div class="fecharmodal">
            <a href="#home" title="Fechar">
                <img src="closebutton.png" alt="Fechar" title="Fechar" border="0" />
            </a>

        </div>
</div>
```

Essa modal fica oculta e aparece depois de 3 segundos. Segue CSS e Javascript:

No CSS

```
*{margin:0; padding:0;}

#fundo{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:url(fundo.png);
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    display:none;
}

#fundo .janelamodal{
    width:350;
    height:260px;
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    margin-left:-175px;
    margin-top:-130px;
    padding:5px;
    background:#FFF;
    border-radius:4px;
}

#fundo .fecharmodal{
    position:absolute;
    right:-11px;
    top:-11px;
    }
```

No javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#fundo").fadeIn();
    $(".fecharmodal").click(function(){
        $("#fundo").fadeOut();
    });
    }, 3000);
});
```

Eu fiz referência ao botão fechar, incluindo a hash `#home` e a minha ideia seria, se possível, fazer uma busca pela hash na url e se possuir essa hash, não exibir a janela modal para o visitante novamente. Para q não fique chato de navegar pelo site. Então a janela só apareceria, caso a sessão fosse fechada.

Answer (score 3):

Usando JQuery com um *plugin* para trabalhar com cookies podemos chegar no resultado desejado:

Link para o plugin:
http://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/

Exemplo de aplicação no seu código:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var mostrou = $.cookie('mostrou');
   if (mostrou == null) {
      setTimeout(function(){
         $.cookie('mostrou','sim');
         $("#fundo").fadeIn();
         $(".fecharmodal").click(function(){
            $("#fundo").fadeOut();
         });
      }, 3000);
   }
});
```

Primeiro recuperamos o  *cookie* de nome "mostrou".
Se ele for nulo, mostramos o modal e setamos ele para "sim".
Se ele existir, o modal não aparece.

Para usar cookies em JS puro, o SOzão tem algumas referências:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825683

Assim como a MDN também tem bons exemplos:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document/cookie